# Minimum distance between functions in $L^{2}(-\pi, \pi)$

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $f(x)=x^{3}$ in $L^{2}(-\pi, \pi)$. Find the coefficients $A, B, C \in \mathbb{R}$ of the function $$g(x)=A\sin{x}+B\cos{x}+C$$ such that the distance between $f$ and $g$ (in the sense of the metric induced by the norm $||\cdot||_{L^{2}(-\pi,\pi)}$) is minimum.

Am I supposed to consider $$\bigg(\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \big(A\sin{x}+B\cos{x}+C-x^{3}\big)^{2} \mathop{dx} \bigg)^{\frac{1}{2}}?$$
I'd appreciate a detailed explanation as the minimum distance notion in functional analysis confuses me a bit.

Comment: Suppose $x$ is a vector in Hilbert Space and $M$ is a closed subspace. The distance between $x$ and $M$ is the distance between $x$ and the orthogonal projection of $x$ onto $M$. Now apply this to Rudin's exercise.

Answer (score 0):

You get minimum distance with the orthogonal projection of $x^3$ to the space generated by $\sin(x),\cos(x),1$.

We need to find $g=A\sin+B\cos+C$ such that $(f-g)\cdot h=0$ for $h=\sin, \cos, 1$. Here $\cdot$ is the dot product in your space

Therefore 
\begin{align}
f\cdot \sin&=A\sin\cdot \sin+B\cos\cdot\sin + C1\cdot \sin\\
f\cdot \cos&=A\sin\cdot\cos+B\cos\cdot\cos + C1\cdot \cos\\
f\cdot 1&=A\sin\cdot1+B\cos\cdot1 + C1\cdot 1\\
\end{align}

This is a system of equations that gives you $A,B,C$.

Comment: There should be an $=0$ for each of the equations.

Comment: @GregordeCillia no.

Comment: Yes, you're right.

Comment: How do you know that there is a solution for your system of equations?

Comment: @uniquesolution I have more than 20 years experience in research in Mathematics. Don't test me with questions that you know the answers.

Comment: @Bettybel - Once you decided to post an answer, it is out there for criticism. It is not personal. This is mathematics. If I were you, I would just compute $A,B,C$.

Comment: @uniquesolution Yes, it is out there for criticism. You haven't raised any so far. Go do something productive like posting your own answer where you can ramble as much as you like.

Comment: @Bettybel - Your solution is incomplete, as it assumes that the system of equations you wrote down has a solution, an assumption that requires proof.