# Minimum Euclidean point-wise distance between two polynomials (and in general continuous functions)

Tags: geometry, metric-spaces

Given two polynomials $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ of the same degree $k$ in a bounded domain of $x\in[-1, 1]$, I want to compute the minimum separation distance between the two functions $h(x) = f(x) - g(x)$.

Of course, I can go about this in multiple ways.

1. Differentiate $h(x)$ and solve when this is 0, to sub back into $h(x)$.
2. An optimisation that $\min{h(x)}, \text{s.t. } -1\leq x \leq 1$
3. Sample across different points in the two functions and find the minimum.

Apart from 1, I need to iterate/ sample across multiple points and evaluate the function at these different points, which I think is very expensive if I want to do this kind of process for thousands of polynomial function pairs.

This is why I was interested in the idea of functional metrics that give an indication of the shortest distance between polynomials and wanted to know if such a thing existed?

All sources I have been able to find on this topic provide an answer to some norm of the separation vector such as the below, but not the actual minimum point-wise Euclidean distance.

- [Minimum distance between functions in $L^{2}(-\pi, \pi)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2340645/minimum-distance-between-functions-in-l2-pi-pi)
- [A simple similarity function for polynomial curves](https://asymptoticlabs.com/blog/posts/a-simple-similarity-function-for-polynomial-curves.html)

Both links are really interesting in that they convert polynomials expressed in monomial bases to a different representation with orthonormal bases (such as Legendre) and compute the distance between the coefficient vectors, which give an indication of the sum of the separation between $f$ and $g$.

Apologies in advance if this is a trivial question, but I am not so familiar with functional analysis and could not find this information in the course notes that I found online. I think what I'm trying to do is to find a functional metric (and an appropriate representation) that gives me an indication of a point-wise metric of two points within given functions at a particular value of $x$ and I'm not sure if this is possible.

Another thing to note is that I don't really care if it's the true minimum, an approximation is ok too.